# Why am I getting a syntax error in script mode and not in interactive mode?

Tags: python

I'm running the following Python code as a script in the terminal.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  
for row in a:
    for col in row:            
        print(col, end=' ')    
    print("\n")
```

I get the following syntax error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, _Error)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 119, in _get_module_details
    code = loader.get_code(mod_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 281, in get_code
    self.code = compile(source, self.filename, 'exec')
  File "/Users/josephizaguirre/Downloads/ps1/pythonPlayground.py", line 6
    print(col, end=' ')
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, when the same code is ran in interactive mode, the code works just fine. What's going on?

Comment: Looks like different versions of python may be installed. Syntax for `print` is different in 2.7, which is what this error is showing

Comment: @G.Anderson You're right...why would this be the case though? Both are run through the terminal. And how would I update the script's python version?

Comment: The error message also explicitly names the Python version in use in the file paths...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @G.Anderson for this one. In the terminal I was running the script with:

```
python -m pythonPlayground
```

When I should have been running it with:

```
python3 -m pythonPlayground
```

Answer (score 0):

the syntax `end=` is not allowed in python2.
Try to set the path to python3 in your shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```